# Odoo Outgoing mail server in Digital Ocean

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have installed Odoo 10 in Digital Ocean cloud server. Everything is working fine, except mail server.

I tried to configure using below credentials:

```
smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
port: 465
Connection Security: SSL/TLS
```

But i getting below error:

```
Connection Test Failed! Here is what we got instead:
534
5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?
sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu8
5.7.14 N6WJLa2VeO6zbTjEmFJlqK-
xwZp_DOLSIEZ2dDpT2_fQfnz5Yi50pFTCHFFzsn0Pt_ZtJq
5.7.14 
12dICdnNGK7724UBxx3AVj8artnFYAHbcB1YhrSgL78hH9SwGp30wZUXmRyWmgEB3XIOex
5.7.14 7NiEAEKY03Qnzn_VWeIEDjjksfrTxKX1em_b6ZVfHo0XIwg2cf-
9mhmvLHoR__vVE7-Vcm
5.7.14 ZCFBNwoCwLA__i4SOAuE5UUPIOQEQ> Please log in via your web 
browser and
5.7.14 then try again.
5.7.14 Learn more at
5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t53sm493061qtc.66 
- gsmtp
```

But i have configured in my local machine, it works fine.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically smtp.gmail works on SMTP port: 587

Also the Connection Security: TLS(STARTTLS)

And in the gmail account you will have to login to the corresponding Google account in the browser on the machine.

Hope it works
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration is Ok, you need just to check Allow less secure apps
in you google account, and to do so :

- Log in your google account by browser.
- navigate to https://myaccount.google.com/
- Click on Apps with account access
- Then check Allow less secure apps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **Manage your Google Account** and select **Security**.

[image]

And turn on **2-Step Verification**, after that, you will get the option for **App passwords**

[image]

Now create an **App password** and use that instead of the password in the odoo email configuration settings.